# Dynamic Memory Allocation in C++ structs

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, struct, allocation

I don't understand the syntax required for dynamically allocating members of a struct in c++. Basically, I need to fill char array members to exact size using a temp array and strlen. Here is my struct:

```
struct card
   {
   char *rank;
   char *suit;
   char color;
   bool dealt;
   char *location;
   };
```

Here is the function that uses the struct:

```
bool importCard(card *deckPtr, char *deckName);
```

I created an array of 52 cards and assigned a pointer to it, and passed it to the function as the first parameter. (deckPtr) Here is a loop in the function that is supposed to read in card info to the struct data members.

```
for(index=0;index<52;index++,deckPtr++)
  {

  fin >> *temp;
  charCount=stringLength(temp);
  deckPtr.*rank = new char[charCount+1];
  stringCopy(*temp, deckPtr.*rank);

  fin >> *temp;
  charCount=stringLength(temp);
  deckPtr.*suit = new char[charCount+1];
  stringCopy(*temp, deckPtr.*suit);

  if(deckPtr.*suit==('d')||deckPtr.*suit==('h'))
     {
     (*deckPtr).color='r';
     }
  else
     {
     (*deckPtr).color='b';
     }

  (*deckPtr).dealt=false;

  deckPtr.*location = new char[11];
  stringCopy(unshPtr, deckPtr.*location);

  }
```

I am getting three compile errors: "rank" "suit" and "location" are "not declared in this scope." What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: stringLength and stringCopy are my own functions. I had to write them (this program is a class assignment) but they function the same way as their string library counterparts.

Comment: Are `rank` and `suit` ever more than one character? Also your operator choice is not terribly idiomatic for C++, which is probably part of the problem.

Comment: Don't bother with the `char*`, just use `std::strings`.

Comment: Also, I can't use the arrow operator.

Comment: Rank and suit range from about 3 to 7 characters.

Comment: @user1362548: `char rank[8]`, `char suit[8]` and ignore memory allocation all together.

Comment: Just use `std::string`

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is `deckPtr->rank`, `deckPtr->suit`, `deckPtr->location = new char[...];`.

But your coding style is more like C than C++. Instead, if you use modern C++, with convenient RAII classes like **`std::string`**, your code becomes much more *simplified*: just use `std::string` instead of raw `char*` pointers, and you don't have to pay attention to memory allocation and memory freeing: it's all automatically managed by `std::string` and destructors.

```
#include <string>

struct card
{
   std::string rank;
   std::string suit;
   char color;
   bool dealt;
   std::string location;
};
```

And instead of your custom `stringCopy()` function you can just use the "natural" `operator=` overload for `std::string` (i.e. `destString = sourceString;`).

And to build an array of 52 cards, just use `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<card> cards(52);
```

Again, memory allocation is automatically managed by `std::vector` (and, unlike raw C arrays, you can query the `vector` for its own element count, using its `size()` method).

Comment: if they're not allowed to use the arrow operator, what are the chances they can use STL?

Answer (score 0):

You need `deckPtr->foo` instead of `deckPtr.*foo`

Your problem is that the dereference operator is operating on `foo`, not on `deckPtr`, which makes *no sense* to the C++ compiler, so it uses instead the *pointer to member operator*.  This operator is used to execute member function pointers on an object, which is *completely* different from accessing a member.  Chances are good that in an intro-level c++ class (like it appears you are in) you will never have to worry about using or understanding that operator.

In general, in C/C++ whenever you have a pointer to a struct, you want to use the `->` operator, not `.`.  `foo->bar` is equivalent to `(*foo).bar`, but it keeps you from messing up and forgetting the parentheses.  There's a reason that C had an arrow operator - it's easier and clearer.  In my not-so-humble opinion, teachers that impose such arbitrary restrictions actually teach students to write bad code and reinvent wheels, but I don't have their experience in teaching programming...

Comment: Arrow operator not allowed yet. She wants us to do it the hard way "for practice".

Comment: Maybe you mean (*deckPtr).foo?

Comment: @user1362548: you mean "to get it wrong" or "never really learn C++"? I'm not sure what not using the `->` operator teaches you. That being said, the pointer-to-member operator `.*` is not the same as the `->` operator.

Comment: When I try the arrow I get an imcompatible assignment error of "char* to char[10]"

Comment: @user1362548 On which line?

Comment: @user1362548 "Arrow operator not allowed"?!? What kind of teacher is this, who wants you to use a hammer to drive a screw? Blah!

Comment: @RobertMason on the line where I used the arrow operator. `deckPtr->rank = new char[charCount+1]`

Comment: @user1362548 What compiler do you use? For me this line compiles just fine.

Comment: that should be legal... are you sure that's the correct definition of card?

Comment: Nevermind, it was my fault. I had an old "card" struct using static allocation. The new one was "newCard". I declared the array as `new card[52]` instead of `new newCard[52]`. My labels defeated me.

Comment: New for the stringCopy lines... what is the correct syntax? I don't know where to use the dereference operator...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `deckPtr->rank`, `deckPtr->suit`, and `deckPtr->location` to assign something to the `char` pointers (alternatively, `(*deckPtr).rank` etc.). Note that `*` in `char *var` is not part of the name of the variable. It just states that the variable is a pointer to `char`.